# SQL Server 2012 SP2 error 5179

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following error when creating a new database in SQL Server 2012:

> because it is on a volume with sector size 2097152. SQL Server supports a maximum sector size of 4096 bytes. Move the file to a volume with a compatible sector size.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. (Microsoft SQL Server , Error : 5179 )

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft SQL Server currently supports the following sector sizes
>   that are equal to or less than 4 kilobytes (KB):
>
> Physical sector sizes that evenly divide into 4 KB 
>   Physical sector sizes that are smaller than the size of the original formatted sector size of the database, as long as the smaller
>   sector size is evenly divisible into the originally formatted sector
>   size
>   512 bytes
>   1,024 bytes
>   2,048 bytes
>   4,096 bytes

*Source* [`Hard disk drive sector-size support boundaries in SQL Server`](http://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/926930/en-us)